# WxWidgets, Printing data from file

Tags: file, wxwidgets

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph2lc.jpg)

I have a problem, can someone explain me how to print data from file in wxwidgets?

i have my data here

```
std::string data_from_file;
file.Open();

while(!file.Eof()){
data_from_file= file.GetNextLine();
}
file.Close();
```

how i can print it on frame like normal cout in c++?

Comment: u mean print to the printer? or draw on the screen? did you check the printing sample?

Comment: I think draw on the screen i can even find a simple example how to do it, can you explain?

Comment: what kind of data? how do you want them to be rendered? can u make a sketch on a paper?

Comment: I edited my question, there is photo about the data. I just want to print it on my frame like there. Normal text data form file

Comment: there is a way to embed an image in the question. Please do so. The links to 3rd party site tends to disappear, go away, expire, etc.

Comment: I did it i think. It is at the top of the page and name "Example".

Comment: you can try to use wxTextCtrl or better use wxGrid. Take a look at the documentation an grid/widgets samples.